# How to create a build by another developer

Tags: objective-c

I've been working on an Obj-c/XCode project for many months and I've recently hired another developer to finish it off.

We want to put the project on TestFlight so the whole team can test it.

The project is setup on my own Apple developer account.

Is it possible for me to create the certs including the necessary uDID's on my own developer account and then send them to the other developer to include in his build? or is that not possible? if so how can he be able to build the project with the appropriate certs etc?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generating the certificates again with all the UDIDs and then send the cert to other developer . Both of you have to install this cert.

Comment: Ok so I can just create the certs myself? he doesn't have to create them? I thought he needed to create them to build with his XCode?

Comment: No , YOU have to generate certs form apple's site, and both of you have to install them.